# Tautology with Natural Deduction

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

I'm trying to prove (p->q) v (q->p) is a tautology. 
I need to start with an assumption, I would start with p->q or q->p but I always get stuck in the assumption. I don't find any way to get out of it to have a disjunction as a 'conclusion'.

Comment: One way is to start with "not p ->q" and show then "q -> p" follows.

Comment: Is there a specific method you need to show it?  There are *many* different methods you can use, e.g. truth-tables, formal proofs, algebra, truth trees, etc. etc.  Or can you just have to work with the truth-functional definitions of the operators involved?

Comment: @Bram28 It would be in this format : [link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjF6vXo8dTiAhVOKFAKHVP9BhwQjRx6BAgBEAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmath.meta.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F10228%2Fhow-to-write-natural-deduction-proofs-at-mse&psig=AOvVaw0eFKFed8wJdcCd49VRv719&ust=1559911627037576) I thought Natural Deduction directly meant this, sorry for the confusion

Comment: @EmmaVandeWouwer Oh, I didn't see the title, my fault!   Still, even within Natural Deduction there are many variants in terms of how the rules are exactly defined.  I think it would be good if you could post your own attempt at a proof: it shows effort on the part of the OP (something we are always looking for at MSE!), and it allows us to give more detailed feedback and help

Comment: As both the current answers suggest, you'll have to use the law of excluded middle or an equivalent. This is because this formula is not constructively provable. A quick way to see that is using the fact that intuitionistic (but *not* classical) propositional logic has the [disjunction property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_and_existence_properties#Disjunction_property) which would imply that we could prove either $P\to Q$ or $Q\to P$ which we clearly can't.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use *Excluded Middle* : $q \lor \lnot q$.

From $q$ derive $p \to q$ by $\to$-intro, followed by $(p \to q) \lor (q \to p)$ by $\lor$-intro.

From $\lnot q$, assuming $q$, derive $p$ by EFQ and then $q \to p$ by $\to$-intro, discharging $q$. Then, again, $(p \to q) \lor (q \to p)$ by $\lor$-intro.

The conclusion follows from EM by $\lor$-elim.

Comment: This started as a hint but stopped being one after the edit. Do you want to use a spoiler tag (`>!` blockquote)?

Answer (score 1):

HINT

Use a Proof by Contradiction. So, your assumption would be that this statement is *not* true ... and then show that that assumption leads to a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

This answer uses the law of the excluded middle as Mauro ALLEGRANZA suggested, but puts a proof in the Fitch-style format.

[image]

To use the law of the excluded middle (LEM) in this proof checker I need to consider two contradictory cases, $Q$ and $\lnot Q$, and derive the desired result, $(P \to Q) \lor (Q \to P)$, from both cases in separate subproofs.  The first case was considered on lines 1-5 and the second on lines 6-11. After getting the same result I could use the LEM rule on line 12 referencing both subproofs.

In the first case, I used reiteration (R), conditional introduction (→I) and disjunction introduction (vI). In the second case, I used contradiction introduction (⊥I), explosion (X), conditional introduction (→I) and disjunction introduction (vI).

More information about the inference rules and the proof checker can be found in the links below.

---

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

P. D. Magnus, Tim Button with additions by J. Robert Loftis remixed and revised by Aaron Thomas-Bolduc, Richard Zach, forallx Calgary Remix: An Introduction to Formal Logic, Winter 2018.